# I have try simple splitter with jquery but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have 2 div one div class is ".section" and another div class name is "more-section-wrapper" and "more-section-wrapper" having header class called "more-section-header". Onclick on more-section-header i am try to adjust the both divs width as like below

```
$(".more-sections-wrapper").css("width","20px");
                    $(".sections").css("width","810px");
```

after that I try to remove the more-sections-wrapper and adding new class name less-section-wrapper and I did above width adjustment onclick of the less-section-wrapper.

I try to do splitter but on click .more-section-header class width was adjusted but after click on less-section-wrapper class it not work.

please check my code below.

```
$(".more-section-header").click(function() {
    $(".more-sections-wrapper").css("width","20px");
    $(".sections").css("width","810px");
    $(".more-section-header").removeClass('more-section-header').addClass('less-section-header');
    }).find(".less-section-header").click(function() {
        $(".less-sections-wrapper").css("width","347px");
        $(".sections").css("width","495px");
        $(".less-section-header").removeClass('less-section-header').addClass('more-section-header');
  });
```

HTML structure as below

```
           -----------------------------------------------
           |                        |                     |
           |                        |                     |
           |                        |                     |
           |                        |                     |
           |                        |                     |
           ------------------------------------------------
```

Please suggestion a solution to implement the simple splitter in jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pk5zW/) what you are trying to achive?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pk5zW/10/) is the animate version.

Comment: Thanks Nalum but How to add animate function.